# MySQL INSERT with duplicate support

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to use a MySQL database to save player information, but whenever there is a duplicate it will load (or save?) every player from the same player column.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
public boolean saveGame(String playerName, String playerPass) {
    String player = "'" + playerName + "', '" + playerPass + "'";
    String player2 = "`password` = '" + playerPass + "'";

    String playerData = "'" + playerName + "', 'testtttt'";
    String playerData2 = "`test` = 'testtttt'";

    Server.getConnectionPool().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO player (username, password) VALUES (" + player + ") ON duplicate KEY UPDATE " + player2);
    Server.getConnectionPool().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO playerdata (username, test) VALUES (" + playerData + ") ON duplicate KEY UPDATE " + playerData2);
    return true;
}

public int loadGame(String name, String pass) {
    ResultSet res = Server.getConnectionPool().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM player, playerdata WHERE player.username = '" + name + "'");
    try {
        name = res.getString("username");
        if (!pass.equalsIgnoreCase(res.getString("password"))) {
            return 3;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here are the schemas (I removed the data from the example as it's not really needed, it doesn't load/save properly regardless):

Player:
[image http://puu.sh/Alit.png](http://puu.sh/Alit.png)

Playerdata:
[image http://puu.sh/Aljr.png](http://puu.sh/Aljr.png)

I'm aware they'll be the same because I'm using the same string for the `test` field, but even if I do random ones or custom edit it in PHPMyAdmin it'll still save and then load from the same column.  I think that it's saving because it seems to load the player properly, it's just not updating the proper column, which I don't know how to do. Inside the `playerdata` table all of the data for every single person is the same, and I don't know what's causing it, any ideas?

Comment: You should really look at using prepared statements here. You will secure your code and simplify the programming in one fell stroke. And yes, please include your table schema in the question.

Comment: Hard to answer without the schema for the tables.

Comment: I've edited in images of it for you guys. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by changing the loading query to `SELECT * FROM player as p, playerdata as pd WHERE p.username = '" + name + "' AND pd.username = '" + name + "'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert duplicate record in your database, please remove primary key(username) from both tables.so you don't want to insert duplicate records, please use JDBC transactions.The following is sample usage;

```
       Server.getConnectionPool().setAutoCommit(false);
       Server.getConnectionPool().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO player (username, password) VALUES (" + player + ") ON duplicate KEY UPDATE " + player2);
       Server.getConnectionPool().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO playerdata (username, test) VALUES (" + playerData + ") ON duplicate KEY UPDATE " + playerData2);
       Server.getConnectionPool().commit();
```

Details usage can learn [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Comment: I don't want to insert duplicates, I want to update them to avoid using duplicates.